# How to download video with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on video downloader extension for Google Chrome, and it is my first project (I am making Chrome extension for the first time). As I know you should use JavaScript for functionality of extension.

I want to do following: I am on some website where is some video player and i want to let user to download that video. I think [Video Downloader Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/video%20downloader%20plus?hl=en) is related to my purpose. So how can I let user do functional above?

Comment: Please specify your problem to a single concise question and show us what you tried so far.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel As I said i have no idea about how can i donwload video with javascript from any website, so i want hint or example

Comment: It's a very broad topic, quite possibly very complicated as well. Start by inspecting the code of other extensions which you can do easily in devtools. Also learn how to use devtools to facilitate debugging various contexts of extensions.

Comment: yes but how can i inspect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JavaScript to look through the user's DOM.

Take anything that's `<embed>` on the page...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("embed")
```

That's usually a video player. The embed tag has a URL, use JavaScript to parse the URL that's written in the embed tag, you have your video URL. 
if you use JavaScript to navigate to a page, you can effectively download it.

For instance if you used

```
window.location.href = 'VIDEO URL';
```

you would download the video. Example embedded code:

```
   <embed width="420" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
```

Please note: usually people are using iframes now to plop a video onto the page:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

So maybe your code should be able to parse things like YouTube URLs within iframes, as well as embedded videos.

Comment: Yeah I know it sound board but all i wanted was a hint. Thank You. BTW i am js developer but chrome extensions are new challenges for me

Answer (score 3):

```
<button onclick="downloadImage()">Download Image</button>
```

```js
function downloadImage() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150', true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
    var tag = document.createElement('a');
    tag.href = imageUrl;
    tag.target = '_blank';
    tag.download = 'sample.png';
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
    tag.click();
    document.body.removeChild(tag);
  };
  xhr.onerror = err => {
    alert('Failed to download picture');
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

If you see cors problem then adds
It will works only download with image and video

Comment: tested with `mp4` and `flv` files of +120Mb, this absolutely works for video as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use it with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
export async function download(url) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()).then(file => {
            const tempUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            const aTag = document.createElement("a");
            aTag.href = tempUrl;
            aTag.download = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
            document.body.appendChild(aTag);
            aTag.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(tempUrl);
            aTag.remove();
            res();
        }).catch(err => {
            rej(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Source: https://www.codingnepalweb.com/download-file-from-url-with-javascript/